# Some rather complex trigonometry for box resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to achieve the ability to resize a box from all 4 corners. This is simple enough but I also want the ability to rotate and still have the anchors hold in place (like any decent photo editing software). I might be overthinking but it turns out to require some complex trig to be able to lock down the anchors like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewplummer/W8tyB/1/

To be clear, there aren't actually multiple boxes in the code... the different boxes are supposed to represent one single box being resized to different sizes from different corners.

This example is very simple at 45 degrees but what I ultimately want is the trig to be able to get the position (left, top) for any size box (rectangles of course too, not just squares) held down at any anchor with any rotation on it.

Direct help welcome but if there are any blog posts on how to formulate the question to answer this problem it might be even more helpful!

Full code:

```
<div id="box1"></div>

<!-- Resizing to 40x40 with the anchor at the top -->
<div id="box2"></div>
<!-- Resizing to 30x30 with the anchor at the top -->
<div id="box3"></div>

<!-- Resizing to 40x40 with the anchor at the left -->
<div id="box4"></div>
<!-- Resizing to 30x30 with the anchor at the left -->
<div id="box5"></div>

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 79px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 87px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

#box4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 79px;
  left: 38px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

#box5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  left: 36px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Why not have all the elements sit in the big box and align to that?

Comment: Sorry isn't meant as real code, but an example of the effect I'm trying to achieve. There's actually only one box and I'm resizing it.. the smaller boxes are examples of how it would resize when a given anchor is applied.

Comment: Not sure how useful it will be to you - but check out diagramo.com - it uses HTML 5 and the canvas, but the math in the JS files should help a lot with what you are doing. This is the file you'll want: http://diagramo.com/editor/lib/handles.js

Comment: Thanks! Actually after having a look at their actual product it seems that they're having some of the same issues that I am. At least it goes to show that it's not a trivial problem! Anyway I think that's setting me in the right direction though so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out... in my case it wasn't as complex as to require a matrix (no skew, scale or translation... all I wanted was height/width and rotation), and it turned out to be simpler than I thought.

In the end the code that worked for me was, as I know the anchors involved, to calculate the distance from the anchor to the center of the rectangle with rotation applied, then move to the top left corner without rotation applied.

```
var offsetX  = rectangleWidth / 2;
var offsetY  = rectangleHeight / 2;

// If we are on the "right/east" side then to get to the
// center the X value needs to be inverted. Likewise for
// the Y value for "bottom/south".
if(anchor.type === 'ne' || anchor.type === 'se') {
  offsetX *= -1;
}
if(anchor.type === 'sw' || anchor.type === 'se') {
  offsetY *= -1;
}

// Get the distance to the center and apply rotation.
var distanceToCenter = new Point(offsetX, offsetY).rotate(rectangle.rotation);
// Distance to the top left corner is always the same regardless of the rotation.
var distanceToTopLeftCorner = new Point(-rectangleWidth / 2, -rectangleHeight / 2);

// And that's it! Getting the x/y position of the rotated rectangle is simply a matter
// of moving to the center of the rectangle (taking rotation into regard), then moving
// to the non-rotated upper left corner (which would be the same as of the rectangle
// had no rotation applied)
var position = anchor.position.add(distanceToCenter).add(distanceToTopLeftCorner);
```